# Resizing the Camera Preview

Tags: android

I have implemented a camera application,  which will show the preview in the entire screen of the device. But my requirement is to show the Camera preview in a small screen. My device resolution is 800x480(WxH) i.e, Nexus one. I can able to show the preview in the entire screen without scale down the preview. Its coming perfectly, but when i try show the preview in small screens(part of my total mobile screen), the preview is getting stretched and not looking good.

Is there any way to show the preview correctly in a small screen. I think we need to scale down the image preview. But when i try to scale down the image preview, the android system itself doesn't allowing to set the scaled preview size.

Could any one please help me how to scale the image preview in small screen.

Answer (score 2):

After struggling with this same problem for about a week, I was FINALLY able to get the camera preview to resize itself programmatically! :-D

`preview` is the name of my `SurfaceView` and in this code, I have it set up so that it resizes itself to be half of the width of the `RelativeLayout` that it's in.

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = preview.getLayoutParams();
RelativeLayout myRelLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.myRelLayout);
params.width = (int) (myRelLayout.getWidth()/2);
preview.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Now for your use, you will need to look at the resolution of the preview and then scale down the height or width accordingly based on that resolution.

Comment: Also, on a related note, I was having huge problems with my camera preview being distorted after taking the first picture.  I found out later, that I needed to add this line to my manifest file and it fixed it. :-)

'<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="6"/>'

Answer (score -1):

uday,

Have you tried just changing

```
<android.view.SurfaceView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/ButtonGroup"
        />
```

to something like this....

```
<android.view.SurfaceView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/ButtonGroup"
        />
```

if that's not what you're looking for, maybe you could post your current code so we can take a look at it? :-)

Comment: Thanks Jared for ur reply.. I already tried above suggestions before posting it here.. We can able to reduce the preview size (surface View Size). But the mail Problem here is with the preview screen. It is very difficult to set the camera Preview properly(with out any stretching or shrinking) to the size of the surface view.

Comment: uday,  I'm thinking a possible solution would be, to programmatically determine the size of the picture taken (or the preview), by getting the dimensions, and then programmatically change the size of the preview to have the same aspect ratio?  It would find out which size is too big (width, or height), and then shrink it as much as it needs so it's the proper ratio.  Would that work for you?  If so, let me know and I'll see if I can get that working. :-)